# The moment I import a DLL file, any powershell graph cmdlet is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell

In a script with PowerShell graph cmdlets, when I import a DLL file, the graph cmdlets become unavailable with

Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Get-Command : The term 'Microsoft.Graph.Sites.private\Get-MgSite_List' is not recognized as
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

If I don't import the DLL file, but I import the PSM1 instead, they work

The DLL file has been generated by PSProtector.
https://www.psprotector.com

I tried creating a manifest file but it's not working.

[Without DLL import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbJRE.png)

My module.ps1

```
Function Install-PSGraphModule {
    Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph -Repository PSGallery -RequiredVersion 1.9.6 -SkipPublisherCheck -AllowClobber -Force -ErrorAction Stop
}

Function Get-AllSpoSites {
    Connect-MgGraph

    Get-MgSites -all

}
```

MyScript.ps1

```
import-Module ".\MyModule.dll"  -Global  -DisableNameChecking -Force

Install-PSGraphModule

Get-AllSpoSites
```

With DLL import

[With dll import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEfYP.png)

Comment: Are you executing any methods in the DLL.  Importing just puts the dll into memory and should not affect anything else.  Check Task Manager and see how much memory you have.

Comment: Does it matter which DLL, or will any DLL cause the problem? An MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example) source code make the question much better.

Comment: I have added a MRE to the description, using a psm1 instead of a DLL